# How could I run C++ on Sublime Text 2 for mac?

Tags: c++, sublimetext2

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
   cout << "Hello World";
   return 0;
}
```

When I code simple C++ like that on Sublime Text 2 for Mac, I anytime get this kind of error.

```
File "/Users/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/C++/untitled.cpp", line 3
using namespace std;
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

Do you guys have any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: @Starl1ght: XCode is not a compiler either. But you can run a compiler from it. You can do the same with Sublime.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  How are you compiling the code?

Comment: That's not a C++ compiler. Could be a Java or Python compiler, possibly. Actually my bet is on Node.JS at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to install the Xcode Command Line tools before you can compile from Sublime Text 2.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2339/_index.html